# Run service without restarting when the app is killed

Tags: android

This question might looks like duplicate one.But I dint get the answer so I am posting.I am working 1 android project.user will open the app ,scans finds ble device and he will connect ble devices.when he kills the app the device is disconnected.So I  Thought of using services.I have implemented service with return START_STICKY onStartCommand.Resulting disconnecting ble device and reconnecting.service restarts.I dont want this to be happen.

Please help me
Thank you.

Comment: @ Sachin Gururaj Acharya this is the behavior of START_STICKEY service if you want service to be stopped after destroying the app then put stopWithtask = "true " in service tag of android manifest.xml

Comment: No I dont need to stop service.If I stop  service all ble device will be disconnected.Instead i need service which runs always.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way is using foreground service.

You can take a look at it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)